# vimで①と書かれたeuc-jpのファイルを編集する方法

Tags: windows, vim

Windows上、サクラエディタで作成した、①と書かれたEUC-JP形式のテキストファイルを、
Kaoriya Vimで開くとエンコーディングをEUC-JPと指定しても文字化けします。
ファイルが不正なことは承知していますが、
エンコーディングを変更せずに、Kaoriya Vim上で編集する方法を教えてください。

Comment: EUC-JPには①という文字は存在しません。EUC-JPに似た別のエンコーディングではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

たぶん eucJP-ms なのだと思います。
開き直すなら、

```
:e ++enc=euc-jp-ms
```

でどうでしょうか。